Arrays in PowerShell
I am trying to achieve the following:
systemlist
[
    System
    {
        Navn: "SystemA",
        Uri: ""
    },
    System
    {
        Navn: "SystemB",
        Uri: ""
    }
]

foreach ($system in $systemlist)
{
  # write out name and URI
  Write-Output $system
}

I am having difficulties doing this in PowerShell.
Also additionally I would like to get the URI of for example systemA - if there is something equivalent to lambda expressions in PowerShell.

# Create an array of custom objects with Name, Uri, and Description properties
$systems = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name        = "System1"
        Uri         = "https://system1.example.com"
        Description = "Primary application server"
    },
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name        = "System2"
        Uri         = "https://system2.example.com"
        Description = "Secondary database server"
    },
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name        = "System3"
        Uri         = "https://system3.example.com"
        Description = "Load balancer"
    }
)

# Loop through each system and write out Name, Uri, and Description
foreach ($system in $systems) {
    Write-Output "Name: $($system.Name)"
    Write-Output "URI: $($system.Uri)"
    Write-Output "Description: $($system.Description)"
    Write-Output ""
}


So.. what was that syntax you used for systemlist in your original post??

You can replace the foreach loop with $systems | Format-List (for display only).

@Theo the systemlist was a bit of pseudo code. I was not sure about the syntax. The systems is the same as systemlist

I think you should have explained that in the post. Now people have maybe tried to make some sense out of that where it was totally unnecessary because all you were after was a PowerShell way of defining an array of objects..
